# How to click on span button written inside serveral div tag in Selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on span button written inside div tag. The `div id ="ROOT/Incident Management"` is the subtag of 2 more div tag.

Project code below

Incident Management

I want to click on below Button "Incident Management". The below codes are tried,

```
1. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cwcNavPanel']/div/div[3]/div/span")).click(); 
2. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'x-panel-header-text') and contains(text(), 'Incident Management')]")).click();
3. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-panel-header x-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable x-accordion-hd']//span[@class='x-panel-header-text']")).click();
4. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed']//span[@class='x-panel-header-text']")).click();
```

Project code below

```
<div id="ROOT/Incident Management" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;">
    <div class="x-panel-header x-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable x-accordion-hd" id="ext-gen91" style="cursor: pointer;"> 
      <span class="x-panel-header-text" id="ext-gen95">Incident Management</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Project code below
<div id="ROOT/Incident Management" class="x-panel x-panel-noborder x-tree x-panel-collapsed" style="width: auto;">
   <div class="x-panel-header x-panel-header-noborder x-unselectable x-accordion-hd" id="ext-gen91" style="cursor: pointer;">
       <span class="x-panel-header-text" id="ext-gen95">Incident Management</span>
   </div>
</div>

Comment: There are no issues with your locators, all of them should work. Are you getting any exception? Also, are you adding enough wait time before locating this element?

Comment: Have you tried driver.findElement(By.Id("ext-gen95")).click() ?

Comment: @user2807505 What is the exception if you are getting ?

Comment: @Ywapom I tried your code and getting below exception
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ext-gen95"}
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: @theGuy, I have added 10sec to click

try {
  Thread.sleep(10000);
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

driver.findElement(By.id("ext-gen95")).click();

getting same exception mentioned above

Comment: can you share the page you are working on or more html code before `<div id="ROOT/Incident Management"` because this should be working.

Comment: Probably the element is in a frame that you need to switch to first.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for your quick reply.

I added the below line and it is wroking fine.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@id, 'ext-gen') and text()='Incident Management']")).click();
```

The explanation is: span contains id 'ext-gen'(not exact id but comparable to like command in sql) and having text like 'Incident Management'.